# Good practice using signals and event driven system

Tags: c++, asynchronous-programming, boost, event, signals

I am using signals (specifically Boost `signals2`) to create an event driven protocol API and model.

Most elements have their own signals, and there are usually multiple of each element.

Consider a basic entity, a `user`; amongst others, the user may leave the system, so I need to have a leave signal.

The question is, should the user object itself be passed to the signal handler? I.e.:

```
class user {
    signals<void(user&)> on_leave;
    //...
};
```

If there was `std::bind` and lambda then this decision would be easier to make, but with those passing the user back seems rather redundant, i.e.:

```
user.connect_on_leave(
    [](user& u) {
        //well I could already refer to user if I wanted to
    }
);
```

And same with binding, I could do something like this

```
user.connect_on_leave(std::bind(my_hander, std::ref(usr));
```

Also, generally speaking, is it better for each signal to just pass to the user whatever it's concerned about, or have some sort of `message` type which all signals operate with?

And my final question: at what point should I stop normalising data? If several signals share the same "payload", is it better to have separate signals like,

```
on_change_name(str)
on_msg_sent(str)
on_leave(str)
```

or

```
on_action(action, str)
```

Answer (score 2):

When sending messages/events across a system, you should use specialized data messages for the payload. 
If not, if for example your user class changes, everything that listens to messages that have a user as payload, could be affected by that change as well. 
As to your question about normalizing: it's not because the signals share the same payload now, that they always will in the future. Reusing messages (or message parts) introduces a form of coupling which could hinder you later on when events need to evolve separately from one another.